# Should moderators be given the discretion to award high-scoring badges and privileges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, privileges

Badges and privileges are site-specific, available only to high reputation participants and automatically awarded. In other words, once certain reputation point thresholds are crossed, the appropriate badge (privilege) is automatically given out.

But is this the best way to handle this? What about giving moderators the discretion to decide whether or not these things are awarded?

Comment: What would be the benefit of doing so? Why is that a good thing? I doubt most moderators would want to have this added responsibility, that's before we consider that some people will start asking/pestering them for badges/privileges.

Comment: "Badges and privileges are site-specific, available only to high reputation participants" Thats just wrong, badegs are about anything but rep for the most part and the most useful priviliges don't requier high reputation, I use my 2k priviliges, that can be earned by edits, far more than my 10k ones. This is very ironic considering your last question says mods have too much power and this would be giving the ultimate power over who can do what.

Answer (score 27):

As a moderator...

*Hell no*

It would be actual work for something that can be automated, allows me to show clear bias and is *entirely pointless*.

This is how I see it playing out.

30 seconds after someone hits a privilege level I get pinged. Or someone goes "WHY HAVE I NOT GOT MY $BADGE YET!" (which sometimes still happens when its automatic).

Privileges on SE are about *achievement* not *patronage*. This essentially turns mods from democratically elected friendly sheepdogs, into feudal lords, doling out titles for... whatever.

You'd also have (once again) people begging and demanding, say edit rights, like they try to do for (entirely automatic bans).

This adds complexity, politics (eww) and drama, to a system that actually works really well as is.

Answer (score 23):

Speaking as a moderator on one of the smaller SE sites... No!

The existing system is fair as it awards privileges the same way for everyone without bias or favour.  I can see no good coming from being able to dole out privilege on a grace and favour basis.  It will just result in rancour and discontent on the site.

To look at it another way, moderators can (temporarily) remove privileges if abused by imposing suspensions.

Answer (score 11):

As a regular user everywhere... No!

If I hit some reputation threshold, I expect those shiny things to be delivered to me automatically and without having to bother anyone.

Nyet!